# Accessing data object property via dot notation in custom filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a data object with products array inside.

```
$scope.data = {
products: [
{ name: "Product #1", description: "A product",
category: "Category #1", price: 100 },
{ name: "Product #2", description: "A product",
category: "Category #1", price: 110 },
{ name: "Product #3", description: "A product",
category: "Category #2", price: 210 },
{ name: "Product #4", description: "A product",
category: "Category #3", price: 202 }]
};
```

Then I  have a custom filter and a 'for' loop inside of which I am able to get the category property value by doing `data[i][propertyName]` and not by doing `data[i].propertName`. Can Anyone explain why ?

I am passing data.products through my ng-repeat as a collection and then applying filter to it say `unique: 'category'`

```html
<a ng-repeat="item in data.products | orderBy: 'category' | unique: 'category' " ></a>
```

My filter

```
angular.module('customFilters', [])
.filter('unique', function(){

return function(data, propertyName){
    if(angular.isArray(data) && angular.isString(propertyName)) {
        var results = [];
        var keys = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var val = data[i][propertyName];
            if(angular.isUndefined(keys[val])){
                keys[val] = true;
                results.push(val);
            }
        }

        return results; 
    } else {
        return data;
    }
}
});
```

**My Understanding** is that when i get to `data[i]` I get an item of `{'name' : 'blah', 'category': 'category1'...}` which is an object. So I should be able to get values by accessing dot notation by doing `data[i].propertyName` as well ! 
Please aid/rectify/verify my understanding !

Comment: When you perform `data[i].propertyName`, it will fetch the value using the __key__ `propertyName` __not__ the value of variable `propertyName`, thus you should stick to bracket notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[i].propertyName` fetches `propertyName` property, which you objects don't have. Dot notation can not be (trivially) used to access property name stored in variable, you should use `data[i][propertyName]` or other metaprogramming methods like [Reflect.get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get). Besides, there's a typo in `data[i].propertName`.

Comment: Alright ! Typo occurred because I typed in the code otherwise it was correct. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform `data[i].propertyName`, it will fetch the value using the **key** `propertyName` **not** the value of variable `propertyName`.

Since you need to fetch the key store in variable `propertyName`, you should stick to Bracket notation